# What's the meaning of "0" as prefix in a floating point literal?

Tags: java, floating-point

Using "0" (zero) as a prefix in an integer literal changes its base to octal. This is why

```
System.out.println(010);
```

will print `8`. But using "F" as a suffix

```
System.out.println(010F);
```

will make it float losing octal base (going back to decimal) and will print `10.0`.

Is there any difference between `010F` and `10F`? Has the "0" prefix any kind of meaning when working with floats?

Comment: I know that, I was wondering why Java allows "zero" as a prefix for floating points, given that seems to be... pointless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Java Language Specification, on [Floating Point literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2)

> FloatingPointLiteral:
>
> - DecimalFloatingPointLiteral
> - HexadecimalFloatingPointLiteral
>
> DecimalFloatingPointLiteral:
>
> - **Digits** . [Digits] [ExponentPart] [FloatTypeSuffix]
> - . Digits [ExponentPart] [FloatTypeSuffix]
> - Digits ExponentPart [FloatTypeSuffix]
> - Digits [ExponentPart] FloatTypeSuffix

where `Digits`

> Digits:
>
> - Digit
> - **Digit** [DigitsAndUnderscores] **Digit**
>
> Digit:
>
> - **0**
> - NonZeroDigit
>
> DigitsAndUnderscores:
>
> - DigitOrUnderscore {DigitOrUnderscore}
>
> DigitOrUnderscore:
>
> - Digit
> - _
>
> Underscores:
>
> - _ {_}

You can have any number of leading `0` for floating point literals.

I cannot find anything in the JLS that explains why this is allowed, but I can imagine it simplifies parsing.

Comment: Interesting... by applying the second rule for Digit you can have an arbitary number of zeroes as prefix. Again, I don't get the point of this actually...

Comment: And thanks to your answer I just realised that you can have "Hexadecimal Floating Point Literals" and that, e.g., `0x0.1p0f` is the hex for 0.0625. That's sick!

Comment: @LuigiCortese People who are serious about floating-point use hexadecimal more often than decimal: http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/ (for the same reason that you do not select two bits from an integer `x` by computing `x & 3145728`).

Comment: I supposed that some domain could require such notations. Thanks for the link, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 6):

Octal notation is only used for integers, not for floating point numbers. This is not specific to Java. So the extra 0 has no effect (other than being confusing for the human reader).

Comment: Being more specific, integer literals of both `int` and `long` type can be octal: 010L is still octal. You never stop learning...

Answer (score 3):

Only Integer Literals can be represented in Octal form(Base-8) in Java.

[jls-3.10.1 : Integer Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

Floating point numbers can be represented either in Decimal (or) Hexadecimal form only.

[jls-3.10.2 : Floating Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2)